# How to access GNU Xnee

Tags: menu

I have installed GNU Xnee (Gnee an OS X automator alternative) from the Software Centre but now I cant find it anywhere in the menus.

Here is the output when I run **gnee** in the terminal

```
gaurav@gaurav-HCL-ME-Laptop:~$ gnee 

(gnee:6864): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated

(gnee:6864): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated

(gnee:6864): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated

(gnee:6864): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated

(gnee:6864): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated

(gnee:6864): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated

(gnee:6864): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated

(gnee:6864): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated

(gnee:6864): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated

(gnee:6864): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated
*** glibc detected *** gnee: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08afb638
***
======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/libc.so.6(+0x6c501)[0x53de501] /lib/libc.so.6(+0x6dd70)[0x53dfd70] /lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x53e2e5d] gnee[0x804c9f5] /lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x5388ce7] gnee[0x804c571]
======= Memory map: ======== 00110000-00112000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755679    /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.2600.0 00112000-00113000 r--p 00002000 08:01 2755679    /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.2600.0 00113000-00114000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 2755679    /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.2600.0 00116000-0011a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755370    /usr/lib/libXtst.so.6.1.0 0011a000-0011b000 r--p 00003000 08:01 2755370    /usr/lib/libXtst.so.6.1.0 0011b000-0011c000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 2755370    /usr/lib/libXtst.so.6.1.0 0011c000-00176000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755432    /usr/lib/libbonoboui-2.so.0.0.0 00176000-00177000 r--p 00059000 08:01 2755432    /usr/lib/libbonoboui-2.so.0.0.0 00177000-00179000 rw-p 0005a000 08:01 2755432    /usr/lib/libbonoboui-2.so.0.0.0 00179000-001c8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755428    /usr/lib/libbonobo-2.so.0.0.0 001c8000-001c9000 ---p 0004f000 08:01 2755428    /usr/lib/libbonobo-2.so.0.0.0 001c9000-001cc000 r--p 0004f000 08:01 2755428    /usr/lib/libbonobo-2.so.0.0.0 001cc000-001d3000 rw-p 00052000 08:01 2755428    /usr/lib/libbonobo-2.so.0.0.0 001d3000-00200000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2754521    /usr/lib/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5 00200000-00201000 ---p 0002d000 08:01 2754521    /usr/lib/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5 00201000-00202000 r--p 0002d000 08:01 2754521    /usr/lib/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5 00202000-00204000 rw-p 0002e000 08:01 2754521    /usr/lib/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5 00204000-0021c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755405    /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0.3209.1 0021c000-0021d000 ---p 00018000 08:01 2755405    /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0.3209.1 0021d000-0021e000 r--p 00018000 08:01 2755405    /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0.3209.1 0021e000-0021f000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 2755405    /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0.3209.1 0021f000-00243000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2756035    /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.2800.1 00243000-00244000 r--p 00023000 08:01 2756035    /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.2800.1 00244000-00245000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 2756035    /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.2800.1 00245000-00248000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393403     /lib/libuuid.so.1.3.0 00248000-00249000 r--p 00002000 08:01 393403     /lib/libuuid.so.1.3.0 00249000-0024a000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 393403     /lib/libuuid.so.1.3.0 0024a000-0024c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755415    /usr/lib/libavahi-glib.so.1.0.2 0024c000-0024d000 r--p 00001000 08:01 2755415    /usr/lib/libavahi-glib.so.1.0.2 0024d000-0024e000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 2755415    /usr/lib/libavahi-glib.so.1.0.2 0024e000-00250000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393661     /lib/libutil-2.12.1.so 00250000-00251000 r--p 00001000 08:01 393661     /lib/libutil-2.12.1.so 00251000-00252000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 393661     /lib/libutil-2.12.1.so 00254000-00255000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso] 00255000-0026c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755647    /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.2200.0 0026c000-0026d000 r--p 00017000 08:01 2755647    /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.2200.0 0026d000-0026e000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 2755647    /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.2200.0 0026e000-002ad000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2756031    /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0.2800.1 002ad000-002ae000 ---p 0003f000 08:01 2756031    /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0.2800.1 002ae000-002af000 r--p 0003f000 08:01 2756031    /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0.2800.1 002af000-002b0000 rw-p 00040000 08:01 2756031    /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0.2800.1 002b0000-002be000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755342    /usr/lib/libXext.so.6.4.0 002be000-002bf000 r--p 0000d000 08:01 2755342    /usr/lib/libXext.so.6.4.0 002bf000-002c0000 rw-p 0000e000 08:01 2755342    /usr/lib/libXext.so.6.4.0 002c0000-002c4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755317    /usr/lib/libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0 002c4000-002c5000 r--p 00003000 08:01 2755317    /usr/lib/libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0 002c5000-002c6000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 2755317    /usr/lib/libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0 002c7000-002d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755430    /usr/lib/libbonobo-activation.so.4.0.0 002d9000-002da000 r--p 00012000 08:01 2755430    /usr/lib/libbonobo-activation.so.4.0.0 002da000-002db000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 2755430    /usr/lib/libbonobo-activation.so.4.0.0 002db000-002dc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  002dc000-00370000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755645    /usr/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.2200.0 00370000-00372000 r--p 00094000 08:01 2755645    /usr/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.2200.0 00372000-00373000 rw-p 00096000 08:01 2755645    /usr/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.2200.0 00373000-0038d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755689    /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.1.1 0038d000-0038e000 r--p 00019000 08:01 2755689    /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.1.1 0038e000-0038f000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 2755689    /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.1.1 0038f000-00395000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755619    /usr/lib/libgailutil.so.18.0.1 00395000-00396000 r--p 00005000 08:01 2755619    /usr/lib/libgailutil.so.18.0.1 00396000-00397000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 2755619    /usr/lib/libgailutil.so.18.0.1 00397000-003ac000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755300    /usr/lib/libICE.so.6.3.0 003ac000-003ad000 r--p 00014000 08:01 2755300    /usr/lib/libICE.so.6.3.0 003ad000-003ae000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 2755300    /usr/lib/libICE.so.6.3.0 003ae000-003b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  003b0000-003f0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755715    /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.2600.0 003f0000-003f1000 r--p 00040000 08:01 2755715    /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.2600.0 003f1000-003f2000 rw-p 00041000 08:01 2755715    /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.2600.0 003f2000-0040f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755524    /usr/lib/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.1.0 0040f000-00410000 r--p 0001c000 08:01 2755524    /usr/lib/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.1.0 00410000-00411000 rw-p 0001d000 08:01 2755524    /usr/lib/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.1.0 00411000-00413000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755352    /usr/lib/libXinerama.so.1.0.0 00413000-00414000 r--p 00001000 08:01 2755352    /usr/lib/libXinerama.so.1.0.0 00414000-00415000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 2755352    /usr/lib/libXinerama.so.1.0.0 00416000-0045f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755313    /usr/lib/libORBit-2.so.0.1.0 0045f000-00467000 r--p 00049000 08:01 2755313    /usr/lib/libORBit-2.so.0.1.0 00467000-00469000 rw-p 00051000 08:01 2755313    /usr/lib/libORBit-2.so.0.1.0 00469000-00551000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2755661    /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0.2600.0 00551000-00553000 r--p 000e7000 08:01 2755661    /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0.2600.0 00553000-00554000 rw-p 000e9000 08:01 2755661    /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0.2600.0 00554000-00555000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  00555000-00578000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393365     /lib/libpng12.so.0.44.0 00578000-00579000 r--p 00022000 08:01 393365     /lib/libpng12.so.0.44.0 00579000-0057a000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 393365     /lib/libpng12.so.0.44.0 0057d000-0057f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393656     /lib/libdl-2.12.1.so 0057f000-00580000 r--p 00001000 08:01 393656     /lib/libdl-2.12.1.soAborted
```

Comment: Please, edit your Ask and send your terminal output to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ helping us to keep AskUbuntu clean and polite. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Press ALT+F2 and type **gnee** in the box and press enter.

To add it under **Accessories**:

Goto System-->Preference-->Main Menu

Select **Accessories** in the left side and click **New Item**

[image]
Give any name in the name field and in command field type **gnee** 
[image]

Now this shortcut will be located under accessories menu.

Comment: thanks for the answer karthick, it worked. One more question, How do I locate it in the menus like under accessories?